# How to change target directory of ResourceObject?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I want to change the targed directory name of the command ResourceObject, since now it is User\Béla which has a conflict because of charater é

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here its considered helpful and polite to show the code that creates your problem in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and the error message so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it will inspire great answers.

Comment: Iook at `$LocalBase`. This is certainly what you need.